# Words or phrases to describe factionalism or compartamentalization in an organization

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I am looking for some suggestions for words or phrases to describe the situation when a high degree of formality or competition exists in an organization, company or similar large entity. Several examples:

- There is an instance of a BBC newsreader in a live broadcast saying something to the effect of *"we asked BBC news for comment on this incident, but the head of BBC news did not respond"*
- The production line department on the first floor of a factory, which produces light bulbs, sends a bill for lightbulbs to the accounts department on the second floor
- During World War II, the German armed forces were notorious for detrimental inter-service rivalries, so that the airforce might refused to follow tactically prudent orders from the army *etc*

Comment: stovepipe organization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stovepipe_(organisation), also information silo, also on wikipedia. Your first and second one are not germane really.

Comment: The word "organize" alone suggests "arrange" "assemble" etc.

Comment: @Lambie I agree - however, I found it difficult even to explain for the sake of the post what I meant by the first two examples. Certainly, they feature information silos, but I mean an organization with disparate parts as implied by the two examples.